# Downlode file from express static folder.I trying to downlode file from angular 8 and i used express as backend

Tags: angular, express

I am tyring to downlode file static serve into my front end angular.When i trying to used express res.downlode function it did't send me any response and on angular i get and an message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/notes/downlode/file-1588236321858.jpg" I try something like this

```
router.get('/downlode/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const file = path.resolve(__dirname, `../notes_pdf/file-1588234337804.jpg`);
  res.download(file);
});

api.use('/notes', express.static('notes_pdf'));
dir of folder BackEnd\notes_pdf
```

i used multer to upload a file

on angular i tyring something like

```
 downlodenotes(id) {
    this.downlode.down(id).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```